# How can I see contact photos together with contacts?

Tags: iphone, contacts

Hello everyone I have a quick question I just upgraded  from a my touch to iphone 4s...On my old phone when i looked through my contact list you were able to see a thumbnail image of the contacts photo while looking through your contacts but I noticed with the iphone as your looking through your contacts it doesnt have the thumbnail preview..It only shows picture if you select contact or when the person calls ...Is there a way to configure it? Or is this just the way the phone works..Any help would be greatly aprreciated

Answer (score 1):

So far, on iOS 6.1.3, it is **not possible** to see your conacts’ photos while browsing them using only Apple’s iOS built-in features.

However, using [jailbreak](/questions/tagged/jailbreak) it is possible to change this behavior.

Going the easy way you could just download an application from the App Store. Just search for “photo contacs” or “photo pictures”. Here are some results:

Simple functionality, iOS integrated adress book only:

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/contact-pics/id305056548
- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/visual-contacts/id303155355

Social media features, includes adress book of Facebook (and others):

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/address-it-contact-manager/id475394924
- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/brewster-address-book/id440979190
- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/contactsxl-+-facebook-sync/id364481787
- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/richcontacts-facebook-linkedin/id435839864

(Apps sorted alphabetically, I have tested none of them.)